# Generated wsdl file contains strange message names. WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

In generated wsdl file (form WCF service) there is a strange name template (maybe only for me). For example section describing a method:

```
<wsdl:message name="InterfaceName_MethodName_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MethodName"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

How can i force WCF not to generate *InterfaceName* prefix and *InputMessage* postfix? The same situation is in *OutputMessage* case. I want wsdl to look as shown below:

```
<wsdl:message name="MethodName">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MethodName"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the message element with MessageContract.Supposed your method in the interface looks like this:

```
<OperationContract>
Function methodName(param as String) as Integer
```

Then you must change it  to:

```
<OperationContract>
     Function methodName(param As messageInput) As mesageOutput
```

Add these classes:

```
<MessageContract()> _
    Public Class messageInput

    Private input1 As String

    <DataMember(Name:="input")> _
    Public Property input() As String 
        Get
            Return Me. input1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me. input1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<MessageContract()> _
Public Class mesageOutput

    Private return1 As Integer

    <DataMember(Name:="return")> _
    Public Property return() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me. return1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me. return1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Now your message element has change to this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="methodName">
    <wsdl:input message="messageInput"/>
    <wsdl:output message="messageOutput"> 
</wsdl:operation>
```

**Edit1:**

To change the method name and the action Attribute do this in the interface:

```
<OperationContractAttribute(Action:="actionName", name:="manipulateMethodName" ReplyAction:="actionResonseName")> _
Function methodName(param As messageInput) As mesageOutput
```

Comment: naro, your solution helped me a lot, bt I have another question. Is there any possible way to remove **name** and **Action** attributes from input/output operation parameters?

Comment: Yes you can change it. See Edit1.

Comment: I meant something else. I do not want do change value of these attibutes. I want to completely remove them,

Comment: You can try it with Action:= "*" - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1c3eefd2-62ae-4367-9146-9e790afa3985/remove-action-from-soap-header?forum=wcf

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not working. While consuming a wsdl file I get the following error: "A ServiceContract can have at most one operation an Action = "*". ". 
Maybe I should try with WSDL Export Extension...

Comment: how much method do you have in your service? And which one have the action:= * attribut? Can you post some code? You can define only one action attribute with "*". - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx